# Python / Excel 15 Minute Timestamps to 1 Hour and Sum Vlues

Tags: python, excel, sum, timestamp

i have a Dataset with 15 Minute Timestamps and Values

[image]

I need it hourly like this (summed values all 4 rows):

[image]

How to do this?

My Dataset has 127000 rows...3 Years, so manually is not an option.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you data is in the range A1:B127000

If you have data for every 15 mins, without any gaps, then

1. Enter the number 1 in Cell C1.
2. In cell C2 enter the formula =C1 + 1 this will just give you a column as a counter: 1,2,3,4 etc
3. Drag that formula down approx 31,750 rows! (127000 / 4). Or double-click the bottom right-hand corner of the cell and Excel will fill down for you.
4. In cell D1 enter the formula =INDEX($A$1:$A$127000,C1*4) this will pull out the 4th, 8th, 12th etc time in column A.
5. In cell E1 enter the formula =SUM(OFFSET($B$1,(C1-1)*4,0,4,1)) and again drag this down as many rows as you need.

I suggest you try this out with just 100 of your rows to start with, just the check it is working as you want.